# Use all strings in an array to search through a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, search, psql

Im building a search field for my profile model, the search field takes in a list of skills separated by comas and find the profiles that have those skills. The code splits up the string by comas into multiple strings in an array. Now I am trying to find profiles that have all the skills in that array but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I've tried playing around with PSQL code in where() but I can only seem to get it to work with 1 of the skills.

I am following the advanced search guide by ryan bates.

Profile.rb

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :educations
  has_many :experiences
  has_many :skills
  has_many :awards
  has_many :publications

  def owner? user
    if self.user == user
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

business_search.rb

```
class BusinessSearch < ApplicationRecord
  def profiles
    @profiles ||= find_profiles
  end

  private

  def find_profiles
    profiles = Profile.all
    if self.skills.present?
      profiles = profiles.joins(:skills)
      skills_array(self.skills).each do |skill|
        profiles = profiles.where('skills.name_en = :q or skills.name_ar = :q', q: skill)
      end
    end
    profiles
  end

  def skills_array(skills)
    return skills.split(/,/)
  end
end
```

business_search_controller.rb

```
class BusinessSearchesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @search = BusinessSearch.new
  end

  def create
    @search = BusinessSearch.create!(search_params)
    redirect_to @search
  end

  def show
    search = BusinessSearch.find(params[:id])
    @profiles = search.profiles
  end

  private

  def search_params
    params.require(:business_search).permit(:first_name, :education_field, :skills)
  end
end
```

Adavanced search view

```
<h1>Advanced Search</h1>

<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :skills %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :skills %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
def find_profiles
  return Profile.all if skills.blank?

  Profile.joins(:skills)
         .where('skills.name_en IN (:skills) OR skills.name_ar IN (:skills)', skills: skills_array(skills))
         .group('profiles.id')
         .having('COUNT(skills.id) = ?', skills_array(skills).size)
end
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you please explain what's happening in the group() and having() method calls ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
def find_profiles                                                                                                          
  return Profile.all if skills.blank?                                                                                      

  Profile.joins(:skills).where('skills.name_en IN (:skills) OR skills.name_ar IN (:skills)', skills: skills_array(skills))                     
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. This works but it even works when only one of the skills matches even though I would like it to only return results that match all the skills that are in the array. Do you think there's a way to make sure that happens ?